# how to remove recovery partition on galaxy tab4 230

Tags: android, galaxy

I need to configure couple of tablets for correctional facility. one of their requirement is to not have factory reset ability. I searched a lot and I figured out if I remove recovery partition factory reset would be impossible. That is a great option for me. Does anyone know how I can remove recovery partition.

Comment: This isn't really programming related. You may ask this on the [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check on StackExchange or http://forum.xda-developers.com/